# how to make combination between the fields in 2 columns?

Tags: r, shell, awk

There are always some data including two associating groups(columns). And each column may include several situation seperated by some symbols (the input is common example in biology data). How to split them and keep all of the pairs between columns?

input:

```
$cat input.txt
PEX10       TPRG1L
SKI         MORN1;RER1
MORN1;RER1  TTC34
MORN1;RER1  TP73;WRAP73
BEST4       TCTEX1D4;PLK3;BTBD19
```

output:

```
PEX10       TPRG1L
SKI         MORN1
SKI         RER1
MORN1       TTC34
RER1        TTC34
MORN1       TP73
MORN1       WRAP73
RER1        TP73
RER1        WRAP73
BEST4       TCTEX1D4
BEST4       PLK3
BEST4       BTBD19
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{n=split($1,f1,";"); 
                    m=split($2,f2,";"); 
                    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                      for(j=1;j<=m;j++) 
                        print f1[i], f2[j]}' file

PEX10   TPRG1L
SKI     MORN1
SKI     RER1
MORN1   TTC34
RER1    TTC34
MORN1   TP73
MORN1   WRAP73
RER1    TP73
RER1    WRAP73
BEST4   TCTEX1D4
BEST4   PLK3
BEST4   BTBD19
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
 df <- data.frame(v1 = c("PEX10",       
                      "SKI",         
                      "MORN1;RER1",  
                      "MORN1;RER1",  
                      "BEST4"),
               v2 = c("TPRG1L",
                      "MORN1;RER1",
                      "TTC34",
                      "TP73;WRAP73",
                      "TCTEX1D4;PLK3;BTBD19")) 
    
    v1_cols = sapply(df$v1,function(x) str_count(x,";")) %>% max()
    v2_cols = sapply(df$v2,function(x) str_count(x,";")) %>% max()
    df %>% 
      separate(v1,into=paste0("v1_",c(1:(v1_cols+1))),sep=";") %>% 
      separate(v2,into=paste0("v2_",c(1:(v2_cols+1))),sep=";") %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("v1_"),names_to = "var1",values_to="char") %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("v2_"),names_to = "var2",values_to="char2") %>% 
      dplyr::select(char,char2) %>% 
      dplyr::filter(complete.cases(.))
```